# Proof that structure sheaf of a variety is indeed a sheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory

I am trying to prove to myself that the structure sheaf of an irreducible variety is indeed a sheaf, where the structure sheaf for an irreducible variety $V$ is defined as $\mathcal O_V(U)=\{ f \in k(V): f \text{ is regular on } U \}$ for $U$ open.

Sheaf condition A is clear. That is, if $U$ is open and $U = \cup U_i$ is an open cover, and $f \in \mathcal O_V(U)$ is such that $\forall i$ $f\vert_{U_i} = 0 $, then $f=0$.

Sheaf condition B or glueability is not clear: if $U$ is open and $U = \cup U_i$ is an open cover, and we have $f_i \in \mathcal O_V(U_i)$ such that $\forall i,j$ we have $f_i \vert_{U_i \cap U_j} = f_j \vert_{U_i \cap U_j}$ then there exists $f \in \mathcal O_V(U)$ such that $f \vert_{U_i} = f_i$.

If the above is too trivial to respond, I'd also appreciate a link to the proof. Thank you.

Comment: if $f$ is regular on $U$ and $U'$ is an open subset of $U,$ then $f|_{U'}$ is regular on $U'.$ $f$ may not be defined everywhere, but it is defined on $U$ and everything you are doing inside $U.$

Comment: Dear @Krish, thank you for your comment, but I fully understand that. I don't know how an element $f\vert_{U^{'}} \in \mathcal O_V(U^{'})$ looks like.

Comment: see the post below. does this answer your question?

Comment: Dear @Krish, I did not doubt whether $f\vert_{U^{'}}$ is a regular function on $U^{'}$, but thanks for the proof. In your proof you regard $ f \in \mathcal O_V(U) $ and its restriction as I described it in the part 1 (see the change in my question). However, I'm not sure it's correct, why isn't part 2 correct? How can $f: U \to k$ be regarded as an element of $k(V)$? I'm very sorry if I can't express myself right.

Comment: what is your definition of *regular function*? you seem to confuse with regular function and rational function. structure sheaf is a sheaf of regular functions, not rational functions. anyway, I deleted my answer since it doesn't answer your questions.

Comment: @Krish. My definition of a regular function is: $f \in k(V)$ is regular at $P$ if there exists an expression $f=g/h$ with $g,h \in k[V]$ and $h(P) \neq 0$. A rational function $f \in k(V)$ is a quotient $f=g/h$ with $g,h \in k[V]$ and $h \neq 0$. A priori such $f$ is not a function on $V$, because of zeros of $h$. But if $f \in k(V)$, can I still write that $f: V \to k$, even though I know it is not defined at some points?

Comment: If so, since my definition of $\mathcal O_V(U)$ is $\{ f \in k(V): f \text{ is regular on } U \}$ or equivalently $\{ f \in k(V): U \subseteq \text{dom} f \}$, my element $f \in \mathcal O_V(U)$ "has information" on what $f$ does to all points in $V$, even though undefined at some. By regarding, as you did, $f$ as $f:U \to k$, don't we lose the information  about points in $V$, but not in $U$?

Comment: yes. now you get it. as I mentioned in my very first comment that you don't need to think about anything that lies out side of $U.$ considering $U$ is sufficient.

Comment: @Krish Fine, I agree that what happens outside of U is not important for $\mathcal O_V(U)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f: U \rightarrow k, f(x) = f_i(x)$ if $x \in U_i.$ Since $f_i \vert_{U_i \cap U_j} = f_j \vert_{U_i \cap U_j}, \forall i, j$ this map is well defined and also $f|_{U_i} = f_i$. So we just need to check that whether it is a regular function on $U$ or not. Let $p \in U.$ Then $p \in U_i$ for some $i.$ So, there exists an open nbd $X_p \subseteq U_i$ of $p$ where it can be wriiten as $\frac{g}{h}$ with $h$ non-vanishing on $X_p.$ But the same expression holds for $U$ also. Hence it is regular at $p.$

Comment: Both $g$ and $h$ are in $k[U]$?

Comment: thank you for your patience. I had the exact same idea, but it just seemed too easy to be true!

Comment: @Kristina: you are welcome. also $g, h$ need not be in $k[U].$ they are defined locally, in a nbd of $p.$ actually we don't need these to be in $k[U].$